# Notepad ++ REGEX replace dynamically

Tags: regex, notepad++

I like to replace the following string:

```
INSERT INTO "a"."b" VALUES ('1', '1','abc');
```

to:

```
INSERT INTO "a"."b" VALUES (1, 1,'abc');
```

Ofcourse when is use a replace with '[0-9]*' it will remove both "'1'". Is there a way to overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'(\d+)'
```

You can try this if you dont have integers outside `()`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/nL5yL3/11

or

```
.*\(\K|'(\d+)'
```

If you have integers before `()`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/nL5yL3/13

(`\K` is supported from notepad++ 6.0 onwards)

Comment: @AvinashRaj yeah i have a different answer,based on conditions.

Comment: op wants to replace remove the single quotes where the number present in it. I didn't find anything than that.

Comment: @AvinashRaj i guess he would not want to remove the values which are not inside `()`.

Comment: Great answer. May i ask why my question got downvoted?

Comment: @jipje44 try to explain your question briefly.

Answer (score 0):

**Find what:**

```
'(\d+)'
```

**Replace with:**

```
$1
```

or `\1`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nL5yL3/12)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following as the find string:

```
'([0-9]+)'
```

And the following as the replace string:

```
\1
```